# need some tips on my code, my code doesn't change text on Android

Tags: java, android

This code to change text when the user presses a button doesn't work. i tried to change it in some ways but i can't figure out why won't it change... please give me a bit help

```
package com.cookbook.simple_activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity extends Activity {
    private TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);


   startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.setText(R.string.pressthisbutton);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Just move the definition of `TextView` and `Button` inside your `onCreate` method. Rest everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
    public class activity extends Activity {
    private TextView txt;
    Button startButton;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
```

You need to initialize your `Views` after inflating your `layout` with `setContentView()`. Since your `Views` exist in your `layout`, they will return `null` if you haven't inflated your `layout` first. You can declare them before your `setContentView()` but you can't initialize them until after.

Also, since you are trying to access `txt` inside your `listener` it must either be `final` or declared as a member variable as above.

This was a rather easy one to spot but they aren't always. When you post a question try to describe what isn't working and how. Here it would be a `NPE` I'm guessing when you try to set the `listener` on your `Button` so it crashes. When it does crash, please provide the logcat so it is easier for us to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.cookbook.simple_activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);


   startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt.setText("your text");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

try this, I moved your button and textview declaring to the body of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

android life cycle always starts with `onCreate()` method assign the id inside the `onCreate`

don't use private modifer for the `TextView`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity extends Activity {
     TextView txt; 
    Button startButton;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
          txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
     startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);


   startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            txt.setText(R.string.pressthisbutton);

        }
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize your textview and other widgets in oncreate method  other wise youll get **NullPointerException**

Try this way

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);

    txt.setText("It Working Now!!");
```